# How to escape a pre-set variable (has a dash in it)

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a variable in javascript that contains a hyphen that is being set via php based on some other code.  I need to figure out the best way to escape this allowing the code to process this is as string and not as a means of subtraction.  The only character it has in it right now outside of numbers is a - (hyphen)

**order_id is the variable that contains the hyphen.**

I call the function via `onclick="print_address_labels('. $order_id .');"`

```
function print_address_labels(order_id) { 

var win = window.open('https://www.example.com/print_address.php?order_id=' + order_id, 'Print Label' ,'width=1300,height=500,left=100,top=200');
var wintimer = setInterval(function() {   
    if(win.closed) {  
        clearInterval(wintimer);  
        window.history.back(); 
    }  
}, 1000);

    }
```

I need 1234-1 to actually put 1234-1 in the link.  What is is doing down is putting 1233 because it is subtracting 1 from 1234.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

Comment: Could you add some more code with regards to your PHP/HTML template? Because it looks to me like you're calling the onclick function wrong but you could be echoing an entire html string.

Comment: How am I calling the onclick wrong?  I didn't paste more code on that because it wasn't necessarily relevent to my question.  Its a simple form onclick of submit, do this.

Comment: It ended up being I needed to escape the onclick function rather than trying to escape it inside the javascript function.  The onclick works perfectly.

Comment: I'm just unsure why you can simply drop in a php variable in to an html form, without using php tags. Simply just defined a variable, so I wasn't sure if you were echoing out a piece of html. I just wanted clarification, since at first glance it looks like your javascript variable is a string of  `. $order_id .` when you meant to call a PHP variable.

Comment: oh yeah I cut out all the php code except for that because the question wasn't related to php.  I get what you are saying now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the value, since it's a string.

```
onclick="print_address_labels(\''. $order_id .'\');"
```

Comment: The entire time I was trying to figure out a way to escape it inside the javascript function.  haha.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks!